# How change name in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/v857V/) is my jquery code and as you can see it's in english - it's a countdown.

I need to set it in italian, i mean "days, hours, minutes and seconds".

How can i do it?
I've tried for two days, but without results :-(
Thank you a lot!

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.county = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({ endDateTime: new Date(), animation: 'fade', reflection: true, reflectionOpacity: 0.2, speed: 500, theme: 'black' }, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            var timeoutInterval = null;
            var container = $(this);
            container.addClass('county ' + settings.theme);
            container.append('<span class="county-days-wrapper first"><span class="county-days">000</span></span><span class="county-hours-wrapper separator-left border-separator-right"><span class="county-hours">00</span></span><span class="county-minutes-wrapper separator-left separator-left"><span class="county-minutes">00</span></span><span class="county-seconds-wrapper separator-left last"><span class="county-seconds">00</span></span><div class="clear"></div><span class="county-label-days">Days</span><span class="county-label-hours">Hours</span><span class="county-label-minutes">Minutes</span><span class="county-label-seconds">Seconds</span>');
            if (container.attr('id') == undefined || container.attr('id') == null) {
                container.attr('id', Math.random());
            }
            var w = 0;
            container.find('>span').each(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('county-days-wrapper') ||
                $(this).hasClass('county-hours-wrapper') ||
                $(this).hasClass('county-minutes-wrapper') ||
                $(this).hasClass('county-seconds-wrapper'))
                    w += $(this).outerWidth();
            });

            container.css({ width: w });

            container.find('>span>span').each(function () {

                $(this).css({ position: 'absolute', width: $(this).width(), height: $(this).height() });
                $(this).parent().css({ width: $(this).width() });
                var daysLabel = container.find('.county-label-days');
                var hoursLabel = container.find('.county-label-hours');
                var minutesLabel = container.find('.county-label-minutes');
                var secondsLabel = container.find('.county-label-seconds');
                if ($(this).hasClass('county-days')) {
                    daysLabel.css({ width: $(this).parent().outerWidth() });
                }
                if ($(this).hasClass('county-hours')) {
                    hoursLabel.css({ width: $(this).parent().outerWidth() });
                }
                if ($(this).hasClass('county-minutes')) {
                    minutesLabel.css({ width: $(this).parent().outerWidth() });
                }
                if ($(this).hasClass('county-seconds')) {
                    secondsLabel.css({ width: $(this).parent().outerWidth() });
                }
            });

            var reflectionContainer = container.clone().css({ opacity: settings.reflectionOpacity }).attr('id', container.attr('id') + '-refl').addClass('county-reflection');
            if (settings.reflection)
                container.after(reflectionContainer);

            updateCounter();

            getCountDown();

            function getCountDown() {
                clearTimeout(timeoutInterval);
                timeoutInterval = setTimeout(function () {

                    updateCounter();

                }, 1000);
            }
            function updateCounter() {
                var countDown = getCurrentCountDown();
                var days = container.find('.county-days');
                var hours = container.find('.county-hours');
                var minutes = container.find('.county-minutes');
                var seconds = container.find('.county-seconds');

                var dayVal = days.html();
                var hourVal = hours.html();
                var minuteVal = minutes.html();
                var secondVal = seconds.html();

                if (dayVal == countDown.days) {
                    days.html(countDown.days);
                }
                else {
                    if (settings.reflection)
                        aimateObject(days, reflectionContainer.find('.county-days'), dayVal, countDown.days, settings.animation);
                    else
                        aimateObject(days, null, dayVal, countDown.days, settings.animation);
                }

                if (hourVal == countDown.hours)
                    hours.html(countDown.hours);
                else {
                    if (settings.reflection)
                        aimateObject(hours, reflectionContainer.find('.county-hours'), hourVal, countDown.hours, settings.animation);
                    else
                        aimateObject(hours, null, hourVal, countDown.hours, settings.animation);
                }

                if (minuteVal == countDown.minutes)
                    minutes.html(countDown.minutes);
                else {
                    if (settings.reflection)
                        aimateObject(minutes, reflectionContainer.find('.county-minutes'), minuteVal, countDown.minutes, settings.animation);
                    else
                        aimateObject(minutes, null, minuteVal, countDown.minutes, settings.animation);
                }
                if (secondVal == countDown.seconds)
                    seconds.html(countDown.seconds);
                else {
                    if (settings.reflection)
                        aimateObject(seconds, reflectionContainer.find('.county-seconds'), secondVal, countDown.seconds, settings.animation);
                    else
                        aimateObject(seconds, null, secondVal, countDown.seconds, settings.animation);
                }

                getCountDown();
            }
            function aimateObject(element, reflectionElement, oldValue, newValue, type) {
                if (type == 'fade') {
                    element.fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('fast').html(newValue);
                    if (settings.reflection)
                        reflectionElement.fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('fast').html(newValue);
                }
                else if (type == 'scroll') {
                    var copy = element.clone();
                    var reflectionCopy = null;

                    if (settings.reflection)
                        reflectionCopy = reflectionElement.clone();

                    var marginTop = copy.outerHeight();

                    copy.css({ marginTop: -marginTop });
                    copy.html(newValue);
                    copy.prependTo(element.parent());

                    if (settings.reflection) {
                        reflectionCopy.css({ marginTop: -marginTop });
                        reflectionCopy.html(newValue);
                        reflectionCopy.prependTo(reflectionElement.parent());
                    }

                    element.animate({ marginTop: marginTop }, settings.speed, function () { $(this).remove(); });
                    copy.animate({ marginTop: 0 }, settings.speed, function () { });

                    if (settings.reflection) {
                        reflectionElement.animate({ marginTop: marginTop }, settings.speed, function () { $(this).remove(); });
                        reflectionCopy.animate({ marginTop: 0 }, settings.speed, function () { });
                    }

                }

            }
            function getCurrentCountDown() {

                //var endDateTime = new Date('2012/12/25 10:00:00');
                var currentDateTime = new Date();

                var diff = parseFloat(settings.endDateTime - currentDateTime);

                var seconds = 0;
                var minutes = 0;
                var hours = 0;
                var total = parseFloat(((((diff / 1000.0) / 60.0) / 60.0) / 24.0));

                var days = parseInt(total);

                total -= days;

                total *= 24.0;

                hours = parseInt(total);

                total -= hours;

                total *= 60.0;

                minutes = parseInt(total);

                total -= minutes;

                total *= 60;

                seconds = parseInt(total);

                return { days: formatNumber(Math.max(0, days), true), hours: formatNumber(Math.max(0, hours), false), minutes: formatNumber(Math.max(0, minutes), false), seconds: formatNumber(Math.max(0, seconds), false) };

            }
            function formatNumber(number, isday) {
                var strNumber = number.toString();
                if (!isday) {
                    if (strNumber.length == 1)
                        return '0' + strNumber;
                    else
                        return strNumber;
                }
                else {
                    if (strNumber.length == 1)
                        return '00' + strNumber;
                    else if (strNumber == 2)
                        return '0' + strNumber;
                    else
                        return strNumber;
                }
            }
            function getHunderth(number) {
                var strNumber = '' + number;

                if (strNumber.length == 3)
                    return strNumber.substr(0, 1);
                else
                    return '0';
            }
            function getTenth(number) {

                var strNumber = '' + number;

                if (strNumber.length == 2)
                    return strNumber.substr(0, 1);
                else
                    return '0';
            }

            function getUnit(number) {
                var strNumber = '' + number;

                if (strNumber.length >= 1)
                    return strNumber.substr(0, 1);
                else
                    return '0';
            }
            return this;
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: in italian days is "giorni", hours is "ore", minutes is "minuti" and seconds is "secondi". Just say me where do i have to modify the code... Because i tried to change all the english words "days, seconds, etc." with the italian ones, but then the code doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
container.append('<span class="county-days-wrapper first"><span class="county-days">000</span></span><span class="county-hours-wrapper separator-left border-separator-right"><span class="county-hours">00</span></span><span class="county-minutes-wrapper separator-left separator-left"><span class="county-minutes">00</span></span><span class="county-seconds-wrapper separator-left last"><span class="county-seconds">00</span></span><div class="clear"></div><span class="county-label-days">Days</span><span class="county-label-hours">Hours</span><span class="county-label-minutes">Minutes</span><span class="county-label-seconds">Seconds</span>');
```

into this line

```
container.append('<span class="county-days-wrapper first"><span class="county-days">000</span></span><span class="county-hours-wrapper separator-left border-separator-right"><span class="county-hours">00</span></span><span class="county-minutes-wrapper separator-left separator-left"><span class="county-minutes">00</span></span><span class="county-seconds-wrapper separator-left last"><span class="county-seconds">00</span></span><div class="clear"></div><span class="county-label-days">Giorni</span><span class="county-label-hours">Ore</span><span class="county-label-minutes">Minuti</span><span class="county-label-seconds">Secondi</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need those English text values translated. Then, you would update your code to include those translated values into your labels, as that's where the resulting text seems to be comming from. So:

```
var days = 'days', hr = 'hours', min = 'minutes', sec = 'seconds';
...
// the following line contains the output text, so we use the variables from above here
// instead of hard-coding the English text into those labels
container.append('<span class="county-days-wrapper first"><span class="county-days">000</span></span><span class="county-hours-wrapper separator-left border-separator-right"><span class="county-hours">00</span></span><span class="county-minutes-wrapper separator-left separator-left"><span class="county-minutes">00</span></span><span class="county-seconds-wrapper separator-left last"><span class="county-seconds">00</span></span><div class="clear"></div><span class="county-label-days">' + days + '</span><span class="county-label-hours">' + hr + '</span><span class="county-label-minutes">' + min + '</span><span class="county-label-seconds">' + sec + '</span>');
...
```

Comment: Ok, i'll try right now.

Comment: i've set the html code, but i can't do the same with jquery. cause i don't find 'var days = 'days', hr = 'hours', min = 'minutes', sec = 'seconds';'